# Error when trying to run an update query using innerjoin (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I try to use the following code in a MySQL query but get the error "Operation must use an updateable query" when I try to run it. However if I create another simple update query (without joins and subqueries) it works fine. Stumped at this point. Any ideas?

```
UPDATE IPad
SET Ipad.[case number] = (
    SELECT ipad_damage_history.[case number]
    FROM IPad
    INNER JOIN ipad_damage_history ON IPad.[Apple ID] = ipad_damage_history.[Apple ID]
    WHERE IPad.[case number] IS NULL
      AND IPad.[Apple ID] = ipad_damage_history.[Apple ID]
    )
WHERE Ipad.[Apple ID] = (
    SELECT ipad_damage_history.[Apple ID]
    FROM IPad
    INNER JOIN ipad_damage_history ON IPad.[Apple ID] = ipad_damage_history.[Apple ID]
    WHERE IPad.[case number] IS NULL
      AND IPad.[Apple ID] = ipad_damage_history.[Apple ID]
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

The [] around identifiers is a SQL SERVER thing. In mysql you should use `` ` `` around multi word columns or reserved keywords.

And mysql update allows you to do the inner join directly:

```
UPDATE IPad
INNER JOIN ipad_damage_history 
    ON IPad.`Apple ID` = ipad_damage_history.`Apple ID`
SET Ipad.`case number` = ipad_damage_history.`case number`
WHERE IPad.`case number` IS NULL
      AND IPad.`Apple ID` = ipad_damage_history.`Apple ID`
```